# Browser and z-index issues

Tags: html, css, positioning, z-index, absolute

Hey there. I have an image that I am absolutely positioning. In Firefox it is where it is supposed to be, in Safari it is all whack. What is going on and what is a surefire way to know where it sits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more details, I'd make sure you understand you have a firm understanding of CSS positioning by reading a page [like this one](http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's parent element is set to a position such as relative. I'd start there.